# JQuery Class and Display Toggling

Tags: jquery

I know there is a better way to do the following but I havent had any luck trying to clean it up.

This is for a table of messages where the user can click a row, `message-head`, which will display the `message-body-hidden` to the user as well as change the class of `message-head` to `message-head-active`. It will also change the fontawesome icon. Along with that, any rows that are currently being displayed or are `-active` will be reverted back to their defaults.

How could I clean this up or more easily perform the same tasks?

```
$("table").on("click", "tr.message-head", function () {
    var active = $(this)
    active.toggleClass('message-head-active')

    if($("i",this).hasClass("fa-envelope-open")){
        $("i",this).removeClass("fa-envelope-open")
        $("i",this).addClass("fa-envelope")     
    }else{
        $("i",this).removeClass("fa-envelope")
        $("i",this).addClass("fa-envelope-open")
    }

    var showMe = active.next().find('.message-body-hidden')
    showMe.toggle()

    $("tr.message-head-active").not(active).removeClass('message-head-active')
    $("tr.message-head-active").not(active).addClass('message-head')

    $("tr.message-head").not(active).find('i').removeClass("fa-envelope-open")
    $("tr.message-head").not(active).find('i').addClass("fa-envelope")

    $("td.message-body-hidden").not(showMe).hide()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your revert all logic to the top of the function to avoid having to exclude the newly active item.

Use a stateful class such as `.is-active` instead of `message-head-active`. Means you only have to toggle 1 class rather than 2.

`toggleClass` accepts multiple arguments so you can toggle the FontAwesome classes in one line. This also removes the need for the `hasClass` check.

Store the result of `$("tr.message-head-active")` to a variable and reuse it when reverting the header and the icon.